# Setting one group of radio buttons based on the value of another group

Tags: javascript, html

I have several set of yes no radio buttons

Below is the jquery being used to try and set the Permanent Resident Alien radio button to false when US Citizen radio button is checked. We have confirmed that the var resAlien is correct, and selects the correct radio button, however, when we try to set it to false it doesn't set. Any ideas?
Thank you.

### I'm using Html.RadioButtonFor

```
  <form action="/Declarations" id="declarationsForm" method="post">
    <table width="100%" id="Ken Customer" style="border: thin solid gray">
     <tr>
                <td>Are you a U.S. citizen?</td>
                <td>
                    <input Name="ApplicantPairs[0].PrimaryBorrower.Declarations.USCitizen" class="National" data-val="true" data-val-required="The USCitizen field is required." id="rdoUSCitizen-816198" name="USCitizen" type="radio" value="True" /><label for="Yes">Yes</label>
                    <input Name="ApplicantPairs[0].PrimaryBorrower.Declarations.USCitizen" checked="checked" class="National" id="rdoUSCitizen-816198" name="USCitizen" type="radio" value="False" /><label for="No">No</label>
                </td>
            </tr>    
     <tr>
                <td>Are you a Permanent Resident Alien?</td>
                <td>
                    <input Name="ApplicantPairs[0].PrimaryBorrower.Declarations.PermanentResidentAlien" checked="checked" class="National" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PermanentResidentAlien field is required." id="rdoPermanentResidentAlien-816198" name="PermanentResidentAlien" type="radio" value="True" /><label for="Yes">Yes</label>
                    <input Name="ApplicantPairs[0].PrimaryBorrower.Declarations.PermanentResidentAlien" class="National" id="rdoPermanentResidentAlien-816198" name="PermanentResidentAlien" type="radio" value="False" /><label for="No">No</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

### jQuery

```
  $("#declarationsForm").on('click',
            '.National',
            function() {
                                var btnId = this.id;
                                var typeItem = btnId.substring(0, 3);
                                var dashIndex = btnId.indexOf("-");
                var ctrl = btnId.substring(3, dashIndex);
                var applicantId = btnId.substring(btnId.indexOf("-") + 1);

                var usCit = "rdoUSCitizen-" + applicantId;
                var forNat = "rdoForeignNat-" + applicantId;
                var resAlien = "rdoPermanentResidentAlien-" + applicantId;
                var btn = document.getElementById(btnId);



                      $("#" + resAlien)).prop('checked', false);                   

            });
```

Comment: Please correct the code sampling and narrow down the exact problem or provide jsFiddle/stack snippet.

Comment: Syntax Error: `$("#" + resAlien)).prop('checked', false); `

Comment: This fails cause you have more than 1 `id` with the same value. Each `id` should be unique. The `name` can be the same to ensure only one item in the group is selected, yet the `id` must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues. One is a syntax issue:

```
$("#" + resAlien)).prop('checked', false);
```

This will fail and should be:

```
$("#" + resAlien).prop('checked', false);
```

The second issue is the use of your `id` attribute. They must be unique. As it is now, you have:

```
<input Name="ApplicantPairs[0].PrimaryBorrower.Declarations.PermanentResidentAlien" checked="checked" class="National" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PermanentResidentAlien field is required." id="rdoPermanentResidentAlien-816198" name="PermanentResidentAlien" type="radio" value="True" />
<label for="Yes">Yes</label>
<input Name="ApplicantPairs[0].PrimaryBorrower.Declarations.PermanentResidentAlien" class="National" id="rdoPermanentResidentAlien-816198" name="PermanentResidentAlien" type="radio" value="False" />
<label for="No">No</label>
```

The `id` is set to `rdoPermanentResidentAlien-816198` for both `input` elements. Your script will effectively set `checked` to `false` for both. So it will work, yet it is not proper.

I would advise updating all your element `id` attributes to be unique. This way you can change a `Yes` to a `No` and vice versa as needed.

I also noticed you have duplicate `name` attributes for some of your `input` elements. This will have adverse effects when the form is submitted.

Here is an example you may want to consider: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/oowc613w/